# how to implement url rewriting similar to SO

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to implement SO like functionality on my asp.net MVC site.

For example when user go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/xxxxxxxx

after loading the subject line is concatenated with the url and url becomes like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/xxxxxxxx/rails-sql-search-through-has-one-relationship

Above "/rails-sql-search-through-has-one-relationship " part is added to the url.

In webforms it's simple, I could just use url rewriting. But not sure how to accomplish this in MVC

The following line is from Global.asax file

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

the string that I need to concatenate is in my database so it fetches from there. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: This is called a slug. [Refer this blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/02/21/manipulating-action-method-parameters.aspx/) for an example of creating one using an action filter

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks. can you answer it?

Comment: It late - will have to wait until tomorrow :)

Comment: ok,no problem until then I try to figure out. but please don't forget

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is called a slug route. One way to achieve this is to define a route with an optional `slug` parameter, and in the controller method check if the parameter has been provided

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Question",
    url: "Question/{id}/{slug}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Question", action = "Details", slug = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then in `QuestionController` (assumes an id will always be provided)

```
public ActionResult Details (int id, string slug)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(slug))
    {
        // Look up the slug in the database based on the id, but for testing
        slug = "this-is-a-slug";
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = id, slug = slug });
    }
    var model = db.Questions.Find(id);
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I am passing it this url:http://localhost:58988/question/1/aa-aa and it's giving me resource not found page. do you know why is that?

Comment: neither the MapRoute function is getting hit when I initialte the request by setting break point

Comment: and when I go to http://localhost:58988/question/0/fawad. it says "The view 'fawad' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:"

Comment: Sounds like a issue with the order of the routes. The route I showed should be the first (before the default route)

Comment: ok it working now. But I am returning view() instead of view(model). if I use view(model) it throws "The view 'fawad' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:"

Comment: That would happen if the value of `model` in my code above was the string "fawad". Are your setting `model = slug;`? Without seeing the actual code your using its a bit hard to be sure

Comment: Also just noticed I had a typo - in the `return RedirectToAction()` line - see edit

Comment: actually fawad is the name of one of the views in my application. do u think it may be causing problem?

Comment: Your going to need to ask a new question with the actual code your using. I'm also not sure why you navigating to `../question/0/fawad`? I thought you wanted to navigate to `../question/0` and have it automatically add the slug to it. I don't know what `fawad` is or means, put it could be that you need to replace `Details` with `fawad` in both the route (`action = "fawad"`) and the controller (`public ActionResult fawad (int id, string slug)`? - but that's just a wild guess

Comment: I think its best if you copy my code exactly as it is (add the route as the first route) and create a `QuestionController` and copy the `Details` method into it then create a `Details.cshtml` view to see how it works

Comment: But it's working. All I had to do is to remove model from return view(model).

Comment: can you please answer my new question related to mvc client side?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391510/how-to-embed-javascript-in-asp-net-mvc-view

Comment: I have asked a new question related to MVC. can you please answer it?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403386/js-files-are-not-linking-to-asp-net-mvc-view

Comment: do you know any good tutorial about mvc 3 and entity framework. I have data in sql server database?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a custom route. If you look closely, SO doesn't care about the text part of the URL. So:

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/xxxxxxxx/rails-sql-search-through-has-one-relationship
 AND
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/xxxxxxxx/
```

Will both work. You can easily do that with something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Question",
    "questions/{id}/{title}",
    new { controller = "Question", action = "Details" });
```

The trick is add the "slug" at the end when you create links:

```
@Html.RouteLink(
    "Read more.",
    "Question",
    new { id = question.Id, title = Slugger.ToUrl(question.Title) })
```

Comment: what if my application has two type of pages "questions" and "registration". how I can register two different routes in my application?

Comment: Not sure I follow, you can register more than one route as long as the names are unique