# Scenario based URL in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have a login action method and the corresponding view.
The URL is :  http://website/login

I was asked to show a different URL when the user clicks this website link in another website. For ex: http://website/ExtLogin

But the functionality inside both the action methods should be the same.
I am not allowed to use attribute based routing, please let me know your suggestions. Should I end up repeating the Action methods and the views for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use slug.

You can create what ever url you need using slug

Find more information on this on [how to implement url rewriting similar to SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349412/how-to-implement-url-rewriting-similar-to-so)