# Need some help regarding .net mvc URL routing/rewriting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, url-routing

URL is something like

```
 /home/rawstring13245/rawstring534533453
```

I want the rule that saves only 13245 to parameter and 534533454 to another but ignore raw strings before them.

how to achieve it in route.config file? 
i want this because strings are not parameters , I need only parameters out of string
like:

```
  url:"{controller}/rawstring{action}/rawstring{id}",
```

what to enter in place of raw string? I don't need those strings. and yeah each raw string is of same length= 10

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349412/how-to-implement-url-rewriting-similar-to-so

Comment: slug value will not solve my problem as i have large number of URLs and all that have different raw strings+parameter strings. i can not manually add their values to them already, there should be some method to do it as all raw strings are of same length 10 and parameters strings of same length 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get complete variables as strings and get your desired part by using the sub-string method. Its the quickest solution, i thought it solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering, this looks like the simplest solution to solve my problem.