# pass an id to an actionlink MVC 5 and then call the alias

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system

hello I try to build a small cms. I have manage to store all my content to my database and now I want to call it through a menu from my _layoutpage. 
(I have built my details page)
How can I pass the id for every article in an action link and then at the url to display the alias?

I have used the following code

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("History", null, "SiteContents",new { id ="ArticleDetails/1" }, null)</li>
```

**EDIT**
I correct my code to

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("History", "ArticleDetails", "SiteContents",new { id ="1" }, null)</li>
```

and it works.

Does anyone know how can I bring an alias (I have stored it as a field in my database) to the url so not the id to be appear.
thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you want a 'slug' (i.e like the url in address bar you looking at now)?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. thank you. how can I call it from my db?

Comment: Not clear exactly what you want, but have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349412/how-to-implement-url-rewriting-similar-to-so/30363600#30363600)

Comment: I mean that I have store a slug for every article in my database. How can I call it at the url?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment - did you try the code I linked to?

Comment: Yes I tried it it gives me http://localhost:xxxx/SiteContents/ArticleDetails/1?slug=slug

Comment: Then you have not implemented it correctly :)

Comment: I am still trying :) What I need to put as a parameter at my action link? thank you...

Comment: hey I manage to bring SiteContents/ArticleDetails/1?slug=this-is-a-slug , but why it brings "slug=" and not just the "this-is-a-slug"

Comment: It doesn't. You obviously have made a mistake somewhere. If you use the exact code in the linked answer, then `Question/1` will result in the url being `Question/1/this-is-a-slug` and `Question/1/this-is-a-slug` will result in `Question/1/this-is-a-slug` and `Question/1?slug=this-is-a-slug` will result in `Question/1?slug=this-is-a-slug` In the case of the first one, the code in the `if` block will be executed, and or the other 2 it wont.