# defining MVC routes and controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this mvc route defined.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Author",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Author", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

so my url will be something like this:

http://mysitename.com/Author/AuthorName     - this should bring all quotes of the particular author.
http://mysitename.com/Author/Authorname/QuoteID - this should bring a particular quote of that author.

My controller name is author controller. Is this feasible? If so how should I define the routes and action methods to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean _without defining an action_? And that route definition will not produce either of those urls.

Comment: How should the route be defined then?

Comment: Do you have 2 action methods, one that accepts the author name (for all quotes associated with that author) and a separate method to return a view for a specific QuoteID?

Comment: No I donot have any except the default Index().

Comment: And I assume you do not want the word `Index` in the route (which will be the case with your current route (and the answer just added).

Comment: I assume this brings down to http://mysitename.com/Author/Quote/AuthorName  Is it not possible to have http://mysitename.com/Author/AuthorName  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145712/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-venkat).

Comment: @Venkat Which version of ASP .NET MVC are you using?

Comment: System.web.MVC points to 4.0

Comment: @mridula can you give me your answer. I will try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would typically have 2 separate methods, one for the list of Quotes, and another for the details of a specific quote. Assuming they are

```
public ActionResult Quotes(string author)
```

and

```
public ActionResult QuoteDetails(string author, int id)
```

the your route definitions would be

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "AuthorQuotes",
    url: "Author/{author}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Author", action = "Quotes" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "QuoteDetails",
    url: "Author/{author}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Author", action = "QuoteDetails" }
);
```

and both these need to be before the default route.

As a side note, the author name is not necessary for the 2nd route and you could just use the `id` parameter, and consider using a 'slug' route for the author name (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349412/how-to-implement-url-rewriting-similar-to-so/30363600#30363600) for an example