# How to make optional parameter url in Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Dont't vote Negative if cant solve the prob because i know what you answer thats why iam here at the end.

**Controller**

```
[Route("{Name}")]
    public ActionResult Details(int? id, string Name)
    {          

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Menu menu = db.Menus.Find(id);
        if (menu == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(menu);
    }
```

**Views**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id, Name = item.MenuName })
```

**Route.config.cs**

```
route.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

**Output:**

how to get output like this

localhost:2345/Blog  instead of localhost:2345/Details/id=1?Name=Blog

Comment: You cannot get just `../Blog` (that url would be calling the `Index()` method of `BlogController` assuming your using the default routes). Routes need to be distinguishable. And in any case you also seem to be wanting to pass a value for `id`

Comment: Yes, i am using default routes .how can i achieve it i want to create a dynamic page .so just tell me how will i get this . even changes in route.config.cs or whatever .

Comment: Did you not read my comment - you cannot. And your code makes no sense. Why pass a value for `Name` when you never even use it. And because a value for the `id` will always be `null` (because its not included in the url), then your code will always return `BadRequest` which is a bit pointless.

Comment: My best guess is that you really want a slug route (e.g. as per SO routes), so that you get .../Details/1/Blog` in which case refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349412/how-to-implement-url-rewriting-similar-to-so/30363600#30363600)

Comment: Do you have any example how to get dynamic pages from database. with url like localhost:2345/page

Answer (score 1):

You can't because the url in the RouteConfig has a specific format:
{controller}/{action}/{id}

To get the url you want, you may create **public ActionResult Blog()**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "NoScript",
            url : "noscript",
            defaults : new { controller = "Home", action = "EnableJavaScript"}
            );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",//the specific format
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: i am creating dynamic page just not specific blog i am fetching table using scalffoding andin view part like localhost:2345/Name which i want

Comment: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/21372-How-to-dynamically-generate-pages-from-a-database-table
This article can be helpful

Comment: you dont understand my question, i am saying suppose i have Home controller and i have database list in Index and i want to show that category or list on click details or any view to go through  with the localhost:2345/listName

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a **UserController** with the following methods

```
// match http://..../arrivaler
    public ActionResult Index(string username)
    {
        // displays the home page for a user
    }

    // match http://..../arrivaler/Photos
    public ActionResult Photos(string username)
    {
        // displays a users photos
    }
```

**Route.config.cs**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "User",
            url: "{username}",
            defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Index" },
            constraints: new { username = new UserNameConstraint() }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "UserPhotos",
            url: "{username}/Photos",
            defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Photos" },
            constraints: new { username = new UserNameConstraint() }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }

    public class UserNameConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            List<string> users = new List<string>() { "Bryan", "Stephen" };
            // Get the username from the url
            var username = values["username"].ToString().ToLower();
            // Check for a match (assumes case insensitive)
            return users.Any(x => x.ToLower() == username);
        }
    }
}
```

If the url is .../Arrivaler, it will match the User route and you will execute the Index() method in UserController (and the value of username will be "Arrivaler")

If the url is .../Arrivaler/Photos, it will match the UserPhotos route and you will execute the Photos() method in UserController (and the value of username will be "Arrivaler")

**Note** that the the sample code above hard codes the users, but in reality you will call a service that returns a collection containing the valid user names. To avoid hitting the database each request, you should consider using *MemoryCache* to cache the collection. The code would first check if it exists, and if not populate it, then check if the collection contains the *username*. You would also need to ensure that the cache was invalidated if a new user was added.