# Combining two views in one vs returning two views for same controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In ASP.NET MVC, I have a `BooksController` which provides functionality for viewing books. I want `www.mydomain.com/books` to return a list of all my books (and it's associated "All books" html page), while `www.domain.com/books/c-sharp-for-dummies` to fetch all information for the "C# for dummies" book (again, with it's "Single book" html page).

It's trivial to create an `Index` method with a `bookName` parameter.

```
public class BooksController
{
     public ActionResult Index(string bookName)
     {
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bookName)
         {
           //return all books here
         }
         else
         {
            //return single book here 
         }
     }
}
```

`Index` has it's associated `Index.cshtml` view page, but then I'd have to do a Razor check in the view to ascertain whether to load the "all books" HTML/CSS, or "single book" HTML/CSS - it's like the view contains two pages in one, which I find counter-intuitive.

What is a good (or even conventional) approach to such scenarios? Do I just create two `cshtml` files, one for "all books" and one for "single book", and just return the appropriate view depending on whether a `bookName` parameter was provided or not?

```
public class BooksController
{
     public ActionResult Index(string bookName)
     {
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bookName)
         {
           //return all books viewmodel and related  view             
         }
         else
         {
            //return single book viewmodel and related view 
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: And `Index` method is typically used for displaying a collection of items associated with a controller, and a separate `Details(string bookName)` method is used for displaying the details of a single item

Comment: I would default the view with All books data and have a partial view loaded async to overwrite that data when a book is chosen

Comment: Two views (and optionally two actions) would be a more common approach than a single view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks - if we assume that I didn't want `/details/` as part of my URL (let's say `/books` for all books and `/books/{bookId}/{bookName}` for a single book) - how would you approach that? I can't think of a "better" solution that the one proposed by @Shyju in his answer.

Comment: Shyju's answer does show how to do that (using attribute routing although you can also just defines routes in your `RouteConfig` file as well). You would just use `[Route("books/{bookId}/{bookName}")]` if you want the ID in the route as well (but that suggest you might want slug routing as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349412/how-to-implement-url-rewriting-similar-to-so/30363600#30363600)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create 2 separate action methods in your controller. One for returning the view with all the books and one to return the details of a single book.

You can define routing definition in such a way, so that the request comes for `yourSite/books`, it will be handled by the index action and `yourSite/books/somebookname`, it will be handled by the `Details` action method. Here is how you will do it with [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing).

```
public class BooksController : Controller
{
    [Route("books")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // to do : Get all the books and pass it to the view.
        return View();
    }
    [Route("books/{bookName}")]
    public ActionResult Details(string bookName)
    {
       // to do : Get single book using the bookName parameter
       // and pass that to the view.
       return View();
    }
}
```

Now in your `index.cshtml` view, you can display all the books and in the `Details.cshtml` view, you can display the details of a specific book.

Comment: thanks @Shyju, does that mean that I would have to define `Route` on top of each method? Can a similar effect be achieved using `RouteConfig` instead?

Comment: Yes. You can achieve the same with conventional routing as well (check the  same link). But IMHO, attribute routing is more readable