# How to setup a wildcard route in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The URL for any product details page on our site is like this:
http://example.com/Product/Index/pid219

Where:

- Product - is the name of the controller
- Index - is the name of the method  and
- pid219 - ID of the product

I would like this page to be accessible as
http://example.com/Product/pid219
OR
http://example.com/Product/name-of-the-product/pid219

So, I modified the `RouteConfig.cs` to this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ProductRoute1",
        url: "{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", id = "" }
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
       name: "ProductRoute2",
       url: "{controller}/{ignore}/{id}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", id = "" }
   );
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );            
}
```

The page is now accessible as desired, however, there is a problem in all other pages which make Ajax call on button clicks.
For e.g: The SignIn button click isn't working.

The controller name is SignIn and there are two methods - Index(which loads the page), SignInUser(which is triggered on ajax request)

When I click on the Sign In button, the Index method is hit now instead of the SignInUser method.

```
function SignInUser() {    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("SignInUser", "SignIn")',            
        data: '',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",            
        success: function (response) {                               
        }
    });        
}
```

If we set a new route, should the url in ajax call also needs to be changed.
Please help me, how I can achieve my goal here. Also specify, if the new routes have to be declared before or after the default one.

Comment: It could be because the first route is matched first, unconditionally. You should consider using `constraints` together with `defaults` to make sure you control which particular requests go through this additional route.

Comment: You need to make the first route `url: "Product/{id}",`. For the 2nd also change `{controller}` to `Product`. And to generate a slug route, refer [how to implement url rewriting similar to SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349412/how-to-implement-url-rewriting-similar-to-so/30363600#30363600)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like this page to be accessible as
http://example.com/Product/pid219
OR
http://example.com/Product/name-of-the-product/pid219
For you :

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ProductRoute1",
        url: "Product/{id}",
        defaults: new {controller = "Product", action = "Index", id = "" }
    );
```

http://example.com/Product/name-of-the-product/pid219

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ProductRoute1",
        url: "Product/{*action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", id = "" }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is coming because in the routes whatever route matches first will be used. Sililar to `switch` statement. In your case it matched with

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ProductRoute1",
        url: "{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", id = "" }
    );
```

If the new functionality is needed only in one controller then its better to add the route directly for this. Something like below

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ProductRoute1",
        url: "Product/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", id = "" }
    );
```